# Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' - Receive Object with another object inside Spring

Tags: java, ajax, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to receive from my controller in Spring a Object with another object inside of it, but I got this error:

I'm doing the call with:

```
$("#form").ajaxForm({
type: "POST",
headers: {
    Authorization: $cookieStore.get("userPassword"),
    FeatureName: name,
},
success: function (data) {
    console.log("reload page");


},
dataType: "text"
}).submit();
```

I get the error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.Option' for property 'option'
```

this is the whole output line:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'modelDTO' on field 'option': rejected value [{"id":3,"optionName":"Other"}]; codes [typeMismatch.modelDTO.option,typeMismatch.option,typeMismatch.com.Option,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [modelDTO.option,option]; arguments []; default message [option]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.Option' for property 'option'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [com.Option] for property 'option': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]
```

this is my controller and the DTO

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional 
public @ResponseBody void save(@ModelAttribute("form") ModelDTO model)
...

public class ModelDTO implements Serializable 
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3276874897891652914L;
    private Long userId;
    private Option option;

    public Long getUserId()
    {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId)
    {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Option getOption()
    {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(Option option)
    {
        this.option = option;
    }

}
```

Does spring allow do this work?

Comment: Yes it does... And the problem is your controller...You are sending JSON but are expecting basic model attribute binding. Annotate the method argument with `@RequestBody`. Unless you are doing really weird things...

Comment: I added the `@RequestBody` and I'm getting `POST https://localhost:8443/app/save 415 (Unsupported Media Type)`

Comment: remove `dataType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, I don't need change anything of my code only add `initBinderAll` in the controller where I'm doing the binding. With this solution we can handle the data which are not converting automatically.

like:

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) 
    {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Option.class,  new OptionPropertyEditor());
    }
```

and create the custom `PropertyEditorSupport` like:

```
public class OptionPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending data to your controller through the request method `POST`, you need to annotate your `ModelDTO model` with `@RequestBody` and remove `@ResponseBody` unless your method is actually supposed to return something. Also, make sure the data you send through your form actually matches your `ModelDTO`.